# How to add values of two columns as a value to another column in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this:

```
S.No | (C1) |  (C2)  | (C3) | (C1+C2+C3)
-----------------------------------------------
1    |  2   |   4    |  5   | (I want 11 here)
-----------------------------------------------
2    |  5   |   2    |  0   | (I want 7 here)
-----------------------------------------------
```

How can I write SQL Query for this?

Anybody please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you tried so far?

Comment: Do you want to persist it in the table or to calculate once querying out?

Answer (score 0):

Try this statement.

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY c1 DESC) AS SerialRowNum, c1,c2,c3, (c1 + c2 c3) as Total from table
```

Comment: I want sum of the values of c1, c2, c3 is in c1+c2+c3

Comment: @rajujwala Hi I have updated the statement, check if this is what you need.

Comment: Why the `row_number()` call?

Comment: To get a sequencial number column if you dont have one. If you have one is not necessary

Answer (score 0):

The posudo will looks like:

```
select c1,c2,c3, (c1+c2+c3) as sum from table;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it in the column value then use `VIRTUAL` column in the table as following.

```
Create table your_table_name
(C1 number,
C2 number,
C3 number,
"C1+C2+C3" NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS (C1+C2+C3) VIRTUAL)
```

now, it will be the responsibility of oracle to generate the required value for you.

Cheers!!